# why MD5 collision failed?

Tags: php, md5, implementation, collision

The two data blocks are from [this site](http://www.links.org/?p=6),but failed to produce the collision :

```
var_dump(md5('d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70') == md5('d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70'));
```

Which output a `bool(false)`,is there something I did wrongly?

**EDIT**
Best with a demo?

Answer (score 7):

You are calculating the md5 hash of the ASCII text. You will need to convert the ASCII hex representation to actual binary *bytes*, then run md5 on the blocks.

Comment: How to convert it to binary bytes?

Comment: It looks like PHP may support arbitrary characters inside strings, so try typing: `md5('\xd1\x31\xdd\x02...` However, I'm not certain this will do what you want so some experimentation will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

try this one (according to [this paper](http://cryptography.hyperlink.cz/md5/MD5_collisions.pdf)):

```
<?php
$a = md5("\xA6\x64\xEA\xB8\x89\x04\xC2\xAC\x48\x43\x41\x0E\x0A\x63\x42\x54\x16\x60\x6C\x81\x44\x2D\xD6\x8D\x40\x04\x58\x3E\xB8\xFB\x7F\x89\x55\xAD\x34\x06\x09\xF4\xB3\x02\x83\xE4\x88\x83\x25\x71\x41\x5A\x08\x51\x25\xE8\xF7\xCD\xC9\x9F\xD9\x1D\xBD\xF2\x80\x37\x3C\x5B\x97\x9E\xBD\xB4\x0E\x2A\x6E\x17\xA6\x23\x57\x24\xD1\xDF\x41\xB4\x46\x73\xF9\x96\xF1\x62\x4A\xDD\x10\x29\x31\x67\xD0\x09\xB1\x8F\x75\xA7\x7F\x79\x30\xD9\x5C\xEB\x02\xE8\xAD\xBA\x7A\xC8\x55\x5C\xED\x74\xCA\xDD\x5F\xC9\x93\x6D\xB1\x9B\x4A\xD8\x35\xCC\x67\xE3");
$b = md5("\xA6\x64\xEA\xB8\x89\x04\xC2\xAC\x48\x43\x41\x0E\x0A\x63\x42\x54\x16\x60\x6C\x01\x44\x2D\xD6\x8D\x40\x04\x58\x3E\xB8\xFB\x7F\x89\x55\xAD\x34\x06\x09\xF4\xB3\x02\x83\xE4\x88\x83\x25\xF1\x41\x5A\x08\x51\x25\xE8\xF7\xCD\xC9\x9F\xD9\x1D\xBD\x72\x80\x37\x3C\x5B\x97\x9E\xBD\xB4\x0E\x2A\x6E\x17\xA6\x23\x57\x24\xD1\xDF\x41\xB4\x46\x73\xF9\x16\xF1\x62\x4A\xDD\x10\x29\x31\x67\xD0\x09\xB1\x8F\x75\xA7\x7F\x79\x30\xD9\x5C\xEB\x02\xE8\xAD\xBA\x7A\x48\x55\x5C\xED\x74\xCA\xDD\x5F\xC9\x93\x6D\xB1\x9B\x4A\x58\x35\xCC\x67\xE3");
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!---!-------------------------------------------------------!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!-------------------------------------------------------!------------------

var_dump($a === $b);
```

I have placed exclamation marks where both strings differ.

Answer (score 0):

I ask the [same question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19353/please-tell-me-two-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value).

The string contains hex values. You can convert them by using `hex2bin("d131d...")` or for PHP < 5.4.0 `pack("H*", "d131d...")`:

```
echo md5(hex2bin("d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70"));
```

or

```
echo md5(pack("H*", "d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70");
```